# PHP basics help in WP context - remove a class/function?

Tags: plugins, metabox

(Disclaimer: I am a designer by choice and a programmer only by necessity. Meaning I can somewhat read PHP code, but I have a harder time writing it myself. I wish I could be better though, and this post is an attempt at understanding PHP a bit better. I probably don't know enough to ask this question in theright way or even using the right terms, so please bear with me. )

I have a custom post type plugin that is adding some custom fields to the admin screens, including a video meta box field. **Now I need to remove the video field, and I'm wondering if you can do that fairly easy with some sort of clever unset/unregister/remove function?**

I think I have identified the relevant piece of code from the plugin, but of course I don't want to edit the plugin itself - but rather add some code in a functions file or similar. Can you give me some pointers in the right direction?

```
<?php
/**
 * Class SixTenPressSermonsCustomFields
 */
class SixTenPressSermonsCustomFields extends SixTenPressCustomFields {

/* shortened for sake of the question */

/**
     * Define the custom sermon fields.
     * @return array
     */
    protected function get_file_fields() {
        $this->setting = sixtenpresssermons_get_setting();
        return array(
            array(
                'type'        => 'file',
                'setting'     => 'mp3',
                'label'       => __( 'Audio', 'sixtenpress-sermons' ),
                'description' => __( 'Upload the audio file (MP3 format) or paste the URL for external MP3 (eg, SoundCloud).', 'sixtenpress-sermons' ),
                'library'     => array( 'audio' ),
            ),
            array(
                'type'        => 'file',
                'setting'     => 'video',
                'label'       => __( 'Video', 'sixtenpress-sermons' ),
                'description' => __( 'Upload the video file (MP4 format) or paste the URL for external video (YouTube, Vimeo).', 'sixtenpress-sermons' ),
                'library'     => array( 'video' ),
            ),
            array(
                'type'        => 'file',
                'setting'     => 'file',
                'label'       => __( 'File', 'sixtenpress-sermons' ),
                'description' => __( 'Upload a related file (pdf format). This could be sermon notes or a weekly bulletin.', 'sixtenpress-sermons' ),
                'library'     => array( 'application' ),
            ),
        );
    }
```

Can I use something in the functions.php file to remove the video field above? Like maybe:

```
<?php

function remove_video_field() {
        /* not working, just guessing */
       unset( sixtenpresssermons_get_setting ); 

        /*specify Video option here somehow? */
}

add_action('remove_video_field','SixTenPressSermonsCustomFields');
// also not working, just me guessing here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to see, if the plugin author has used `apply_filters()` in the function that renders the metabox fields. If there is one, then you can attach your filtering function to that hook and remove unnecessary fields from the metabox.

**The code below is pseudo-code and for example use only.**

Inside the class there could be a method (i.e. function) along these lines.

```
public function render_metabox_fields() {
  $fields = apply_filters( 'filter_available_fields', $this->get_file_fields() );
  // some loop code to actually render the fields...  
}
```

*The rendering might also happen in some other part of the codebase - who knows, as with all 3rd party plugins/themes.*

You could then do this in your theme's `functions.php` file,

```
add_filter('filter_available_fields', 'my_descriptive_function_name');
function my_descriptive_function_name( $fields ) {
  // loop available fields which the apply_filter function provides as a parameter for our function
  foreach ($fields as $index => $field) {
    // target only certain items with if statement
    if ( 'video' === $field['setting'] ) {
      // do something with matched items
      unset($fields[$index]);
    }
  }
  // return variable to the apply_filters function so that the original code can continue its operations
  return $fields;
}
```

But, if there are no filtering hooks to attach custom code to, then you're probably out of luck. You better check from the plugin author or documentation.

Comment: Thank you Antti, that was a good explanation. I think I understand the principle. I'll have to look deeper in the plugin and see if this is a suitable option, and if not, I can move on to simply hide the field in CSS knowing that I have looked at doing it "the right way" first. Thank you for taking the time to answer.